# sequence mask in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been following tensorflow documentation for a while.
Recently I found a function `sequence_mask()` which is actually very useful.

According to the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask),

```
sequence_mask(
    lengths,
    maxlen=None,
    dtype=tf.bool,
    name=None
)
```

here they also provided two example,

```
tf.sequence_mask([1, 3, 2], 5)  # [[True, False, False, False, False],
                                #  [True, True, True, False, False],
                                #  [True, True, False, False, False]]

tf.sequence_mask([[1, 3],[2,0]])  # [[[True, False, False],
                                  #   [True, True, True]],
                                  #  [[True, True, False],
                                  #   [False, False, False]]]
```

While I was testing  them in my computer, First example executed successfully. But while I run the second example, there is an error message showed.

```
ValueError: lengths must be 1D for sequence_mask
```

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because of the Tesorflow version that you have installed. Update to Tensorflow version 1.4.0 and should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't know tensorflow 1.4.0 released. I am now using 1.3.0